# How to inherit from base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

Hi My code is as follows

```
public partial class Class1:InheritBase1
{

 public Class1()
 { 
   //Access table1 here
 }

}

public class InheritBase2 
{
     protected DataTable table1{get;set;}
}
```

I need to access **table1** from **InheritBase2** class to my class.

As C# doesn't allow multiple inheritance what are the possible ways to achieve this ?

Thank's all.

Comment: Can you show the class `InheritBase1` please ?

Comment: Is `InheritBase2` in a separate file?

Comment: use an interface. you can't inherit from multiple classes but you can implement more than one interface.

Comment: You have to change your design, or use a language that allows multiple inheritance.

Comment: @Selman22 How can I do that ? example would be good

Comment: Maybe composition would a better way than inheriting.

Comment: Depending on the context, which we do not have enough of, you might either want to change the inheritance chain, as SofiaÖhrn in http://stackoverflow.com/a/25548978/691294, or use composition instead, as MatíasFidemraizer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25548963/691294. Usually composition is better than inheriting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could easily solve this using composition instead of inheritance.

Say there's a class `A` and a class `B`. `A` *has* a `B`.

```
public class A
{
    public B AssociatedB { get; set; }
}
```

### Why...?

> could you please elaborate –  kyle

In object-oriented programming there're two approaches to create relationships between objects. Either of them are necessarily *hierarchical*.

If you end up thinking some object *is* something, we'll be talking about *inheritance*. For example, a *cat* is an *animal*. That is, a class *cat* derives from *animal*.

In the other hand, if you end up thinking some object *has a* X thing, we'll be talking about *composition*. For example, a car *has an* engine.

At the end of the day, if you are using inheritance in order to share a reference to a `DataTable`, I really encourage you to use *composition* instead, because your class *has a* `DataTable`:

```
public class A 
{
    public DataTable Table { get; set; }
}

public class B 
{
    public DataTable Table { get; set; }
}

DataTable someTable = new DataTable();

// Both class instances share the same DataTable
// because you set the same object to both
// class properties
A someA = new A();
someA.Table = someTable;

B someB = new B();
someB.Table = someTable;
```

Comment: could you please elaborate

Answer (score 2):

You can benefit form the composition.

```
class A : B {

}
```

can be replaced as

```
class A {
   B b 
}
```

If you want that A and B can be used in the same contenxt you need to intruduce a interface.

The interface allow you to define abstract functionality and have various implementations for it.

```
interface ISampleInterface
{
    void SampleMethod();
}
```

In case when we have

```
class B : ISampleInterface
{
     void SampleMethod() { 
         //Do some action
     }
}
```

Now your class A can or inherit form B in odrder to access to sample method or use composition.

```
class A : ISampleInterface {

   B b; 

   void SampleMethod() { 
         b.SampleMethod();
     }

}
```

Then i code you can use this like

```
 ISampleInterface  sa = new A(); 
 ISampleInterface  sb = new B();  

  sa.SampleMethod(); //Call B through A
  sb.SampleMethod(); //Call B
```

This is only bired description for more you should follow a tutorial about Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: How can I go by using interface??

Comment: BTW I find this sample of interfaces a bit vague because it shows how to objects might share the same method (obviously, both implement same interface). I believe that, at the end of the day, either using interfaces or not, it suggests that both should provide an association of `DataTable`. It could be solved without interfaces :D